# MYSQL Error 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I want to insert data but i get this error:

```
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`versandhandel`.`Mitarbeiter`, CONSTRAINT `marb_fk_chef` FOREIGN KEY (`Chef_Mitarbeiternummer`) REFERENCES `Mitarbeiter` (`Mitarbeiternummer`))
```

This is my Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Mitarbeiter(
Mitarbeiternummer INT(5),
Personennummer INT(5) NOT NULL,
Gehalt DECIMAL(9,2),
Chef_Mitarbeiternummer INT(5),
constraint mitarbeiter_pk primary key (Mitarbeiternummer),
constraint unique_mitpernr UNIQUE (Personennummer),
constraint marb_fk_persnr foreign key(Personennummer) references Person(Personennummer) ON DELETE CASCADE,
constraint marb_fk_chef foreign key (Chef_Mitarbeiternummer) references Mitarbeiter(Mitarbeiternummer));
```

so i insert data like that:

```
INSERT INTO Mitarbeiter (Mitarbeiternummer, Personennummer, Gehalt)
VALUES ('2', '3','10000');
```

but then i want that my new Mitarbeiter (=employee) has the Mitarbeiter with the number 2 as his Chef (=boss)
so i add

```
INSERT INTO Mitarbeiter VALUES ('4', '6', '9000', '2');
```

but then i get the error above..

It would be nice if anyone could help me :) Thanks

Comment: What error would u got ?

Comment: do you mean the error on the top of my post?

Comment: Foreign keys not set properly, Are u use phpmyadmin

Comment: no i write everything in the shell. how can i set it properly?

Comment: Delete the all values from table and the set the Foreign keys